# Windsor and delegating object creation/registration

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, spring.net

I have been using Spring.NET for about 4-5 years, and have only recently started looking at the Windsor container. There is a lot about Windsor I like, but I also have to support existing sites with the Spring.NET framework.

Is it possible (and if so how), to have Windsor be the controlling DI container, but to incorporate delegating the creation of certain types to a Spring.NET container.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can try to do that with custom activator but be aware that that's asking for trouble and will cause you more grief than biting the bullet and migrating completely. Containers assume ownership of components they manage and having two managers is usually a recipe for disaster.